# Зачем нужен регистр ebp

Tags: ассемблер

Для чего нужен регистр `ebp`, если есть `esp`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Один из типичных способов использования регистра `ebp` - хранение базового адреса [стекового кадра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80).

Если упрощенно, в начале функции состояние регистра `esp` сохраняется в `ebp`, и дальше уже адреса аргументов функции и локальных переменных отсчитываются от него. Дальше, в процессе работы функции (и вызываемых ею функций) `esp` может меняться как угодно, но адрес локальной переменной в этой функции как был, скажем, `ebp-8` так и остается им при любых изменениях `esp`.

При адресации локальных переменных можно обойтись и без `ebp`, но тогда адрес переменной будет рассчитываться как `esp+N+var`, где N зависит от того, какие изменения произошли с `esp` после выделения памяти в стеке под локальные переменные. Современные компиляторы, в общем-то, так и делают, а `ebp` используют для каких-то других целей (например, просто как регистр общего назначения).

---

В 16-битные времена при сложной адресации (базовый регистр + индексный регистр + смещение, т.е., например, `[BP+SI+10h]`) в качестве базового регистра можно было использовать только `bp` и `bx` (`sp` нельзя было использовать в качестве базового регистра, т.е. адресация вида `[SP+N]` невозможна), в качестве индексного - только `si` и `di`. Поэтому, если бы не было `bp`, то пришлось бы обходиться только **одним** базовым регистром (тогда логичнее было бы `bx` переименовать в `bp` (Base Pointer)). При 32-битной адресации разделение не такое строгое, в качестве базового регистра можно использовать любой 32-битный регистр, в качестве индексного - любой кроме `esp`.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, я бы ответствовал так - все это регистры общего назначения, но **в основном** они применяются для работы со стеком (хотя не исключены и иные применения); обычно `esp` указывает **текущее состояние стека**, а `ebp` - начало кадра стека для данного вызова функции, так что не придется мучиться с адресами локальных переменных при каждом изменении в стеке. Например, при дополнительном выделении памяти в стеке или еще чем-то в таком роде.